# pcap to csv only 104asdu protocol with fields noframe,lenframe,apdulen,rx,tx,type,typeid,causetx,ioa,numix,oa

Tags: python, wireshark, tshark

How to convert `pcap` to `csv` with exact that fields? I have already tried it with `tshark,` but all of the data is going in. I need it on the `asdu104` protocol, so I use `-O`. This is my command.

```
tshark -r dataset.pcap -O iec60870_asdu -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.len -e iec60870_104.apdulen -e iec60870_104.type -e iec60870_104.tx -e iec60870_104.rx -e iec60870_asdu.typeid -e iec60870_asdu.causetx -e iec60870_asdu.ioa -e iec60870_asdu.numix -e iec60870_asdu.oa -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv
```

Anyone knows how to do it, or did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, by *"but all of the data is going in."*, you mean that you are getting output for other protocols besides **iec60870_asdu** and you'd only like the output for that protocol alone.  Assuming that's the case, you should only need to make a minor change to your [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) command.  The key is to apply a filter so only packets matching **iec60870_asdu** will be present in the results.  This is accomplished using the `-Y` option, not the `-O` option.  So, the modified command is thus:


`tshark -r dataset.pcap -Y iec60870_asdu -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.len -e iec60870_104.apdulen -e iec60870_104.type -e iec60870_104.tx -e iec60870_104.rx -e iec60870_asdu.typeid -e iec60870_asdu.causetx -e iec60870_asdu.ioa -e iec60870_asdu.numix -e iec60870_asdu.oa -E header=y -E separator=, > output.csv`

And as mentioned in the [`tshark` man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) under the `-T` option, you might also want to add the `-E quote=d` option to your command as well.